# MS SQL Server - Use Calculated Field of SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i would like to ask you if there is a statement to use calculated fields of the same SELECT-statement:

For example:

Table Test:

Machine  Amount  Value
500 20 20

```
SELECT Machine, 
    Amount*Value AS TestFormula
    TestFormula*12 AS TestFormulaYear
FROM Test
```

What is the correct statement to reuse this calculated field?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql server at least, you can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT  Machine 
,       TestFormula
,       TestFormula*12 AS TestFormulaYear
FROM    (
           SELECT Machine 
           ,      Amount*Value AS TestFormula
           FROM   Test
        ) T
```

Answer (score 1):

For the simple example you showed us, I would just recommend repeating the expression

```
SELECT
    Machine, 
    Amount*Value AS TestFormula,
    Amount*Value*12 AS TestFormulaYear
FROM Test;
```

Other answers have already shown how you can use a subquery to truly reuse the column, but that is not very performant compared to what I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [common-table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to reuse the value:

```
WITH formula AS (
    SELECT Machine, 
        Amount*Value AS TestFormula
    FROM Test
    )
SELECT Machine, 
    TestFormula
    TestFormula*12 AS TestFormulaYear
FROM formula;
```

If the batch with the CTE contains multiple statements, the preceding statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is T-SQL:

You can't reference the alias of a column in the `SELECT` statement, no. If you look at [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql) you'll note that the SELECT is the 8th part of the query to be processed. This means only `ORDER BY` is going to be able to reference a column's alias.

If you need to do further calculations on a calculated value you need to use a CTE, subquery, or redeclare the calculation. For example:

**Repeated calculation:**

```
SELECT [Column] * 10 As Expression,
       [Column] * 10 * 5 AS Expression2
FROM [Table];
```

**CTE:**

```
WITH Formula AS(
    SELECT [Column] * 10 As Expression
    FROM [Table])
SELECT Expression,
       Expression * 5 AS Expression2
FROM Formula;
```

**Sub Query:**

```
SELECT Expression,
       Expression * 5 AS Expression2
FROM (SELECT [Column] * 10 As Expression
      FROM [Table]) Formula;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to set up a Statement so that when formulas are changed many columns will be updated, I suppose you could declare the formulas and use Dynamic SQL. There can be an advantage to this if you want to be sure that lots of columns are updated correctly:

```
Declare @TestFormula as nvarchar(100) = '([Amount]*[Value])'
Declare @TestFormulaYear as nvarchar(100) = '(12*' + @TestFormula + ')'
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT [Machine], ' + @TestFormula + ' AS TestFormula, ' + @TestFormulaYear + ' AS TestFormulaYear
FROM (values(500, 20, 20)) a([Machine], [Amount], [Value])'
exec(@sql)
```